# read two different strings of same line from a CSV

Tags: powershell

Sorry, I am a newbie in PowerShell and for this basic one.

I have a CSV file with these contents and with several more lines and wanted to read each line of two variables (Name, User) and run a cmdlet as below.

```
~# cat test.scv

Name, User
mycomputer1, John
mycomputer2, Jake
….
….
mycomputer100, Susan
```

I used Import-CSV to import the file.

```
$csv = Import-CSV “X:\test.csv"
```

This would result as:

```
Name            User
———             ——— 
mycomputer1     John
mycomputer2     Jake
..
..
mycomputer100   Susan
```

How should I modify this script to read each line and use both values (Name, User) in that line to run the Connect-Server cmdlet one at a time?

```
Connect-Server –Server mycomputer1 –User John
Connect-Server –Server mycomputer2 –User Jake
…
…
Connect-Server –Server mycomputer100 –User Susan
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution of "The Shooter" is better, but you can do like this too:

```
$csv = Import-CSV "C:\temp\test.csv"     
foreach ($row in $csv)
{
    Connect-Server -Server $row.Name -User $row.User 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Esperento. This seems working as expected and what I required. I could more commands within foreach statement before connecting to the next computer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Import-Csv C:\temp\ps\cs.txt | ForEach-Object { Connect-Server -Server $_.Name -User $_.User }
```

Comment: Thanks The Shooter. It seems this would run the connect-server all at once.. I would like to have Connect-server on mycomputer1 along with the first user John, and then print something in between and then connect to mycomputer2.  I think this would execute "connect-server" to all instances at a time,

Comment: Was away for a meeting so couldn't reply you in time.